# Emacs is blurry on scaled Windows displays (eg. Surface)

Tags: window, scaling, rendering

To smooth my embedded workflow I have succombed to buying a Microsoft Surface. Like the early days of MacOS retina screens Emacs is all blurry. Does anyone know if there is any support for scaled displays in Windows? Google turns up few results, but it could be I'm not searching for the right feature names, Windows noob and all...

PS: Sorry for the tag - SE thinks I should use the existing tag `window` instead of `windows` :)

Comment: You can increase the font size, remember that Emacs is, in principle, quite well vectorized. :-)

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768200/how-to-get-emacs-text-to-render-as-crisply-as-netbeans , and there are related comments on the same solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645684/emacs-on-windows-8-1-with-font-scaling-for-4k-monitor as well.

Comment: Those previous Q/A's don't really work because Emacs ends up getting blurry when DPI settings get overrides.